# Mongoose Schemme is not validating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, mongoose

I am using mongoose db and have a schema for adding cars to a table, but it seems my entries are not being checked just added straight in? It should show a warring in the terminal or at least just not allow me to add the records.

I cant seem to find anything online about the problem.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const carTypes = `Avensis,Corolla,Yaris`.split(`,`);
let carsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        model: { type: String, enum: carTypes },
        colour: { type: String },
        year: { type: Number, min: 2002 - 02 - 09, max: 2020 - 02 - 09 },
        price: { type: Number, min:1000, max:100000 }
    },
    {
        collection: `cars`
    }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model(`cars`, carsSchema);
```

My other file router page is as follows.

```
const router = require(`express`).Router()
const carsModel = require(`../models/cars`)
// read all records
router.get(`/cars/`, (req, res) => 
{   
    carsModel.find((error, data) => 
    {
        res.json(data)
    })
})
// Read one record
router.get(`/cars/:id`, (req, res) => 
{
    carsModel.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => 
    {
        res.json(data)
    })
})
// Add new record
router.post(`/cars/`, (req, res) => 
{
    carsModel.create(req.body, (error, data) => 
    {
        res.json(data)
    })
})
// Update one record
router.put(`/cars/:id`, (req, res) => 
{
    carsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body}, (error, data) => 
    {
        res.json(data)
    })        
})
// Delete one record
router.delete(`/cars/:id`, (req, res) => 
{
    carsModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (error, data) => 
    {
        res.json(data)
    })       
})
module.exports = router
```

My machine is mac is it something todo with my mongoose set up? The data does add to the database!

Comment: What *specifically* is happening that shouldn't be, and under what conditions?

Comment: Its adding to the Database, when it shouldnt be accepted. Example min value for price is 1000, if i put the price to 20 its still accepted. @DaveNewton

Comment: The [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html#validators) suggest that the Date should be in string format for the year field.

Comment: Unrelated, but your date validation is very odd.